# Bash script to Stow Linux configuration files not working with files in root of home or existing folders

Tags: linux, bash, config, symlink, dotfiles

Basically, I am trying to use `GNU Stow` to easily sync my dotfiles / config files to my home directory. Each config is stored in a named folder relative to my home directory. For example, `vim/.vimrc` or `i3/.config/i3/config`. Some of these folders have multiple files.

**Script**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# This script will Stow all the dotfiles located in the ~/dotfiles folder.
# The -R flag is used to force a 'restow' which will remove any existing symlinks before attempting to Stow.

echo "Stowing Dotfiles...";

cd ~/.dotfiles
for file in ~/dotfiles/*; do
  # Only run Stow on the directories in the dotfiles folder and not the individual files.
  # Using 'basename' strips the filepath from the directory name. 
  if [ -d ${file} ]; then
    stow -R $(basename $file)
    echo "$(basename $file) stowed."; 
  fi
done

# Return back to the your PWD from before you ran the script
cd ~- 

echo 'All stowed';
```

When I run this certain files or directories in the `~/.config` folder are stowed. However, if the file exists it does not seem to get stowed. Also, files in the root of my home directory do not seem to get stowed, such as `bash/.bashrc` and the other files in said dir.

**Output**

```
Stowing Dotfiles...
stow_all.sh: line 8: cd: /home/devon/.dotfiles: No such file or directory
WARNING! unstowing bash would cause conflicts:
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .bash_aliases
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .bashrc
WARNING! stowing bash would cause conflicts:
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .bash_aliases
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .bashrc
All operations aborted.
bash stowed.
bin stowed.
compton stowed.
WARNING! unstowing fonts would cause conflicts:
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/Roboto Mono Bold Italic for Powerline.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/Roboto Mono Bold for Powerline.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/Roboto Mono Italic for Powerline.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/Roboto Mono Light Italic for Powerline.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/Roboto Mono Light for Powerline.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/Roboto Mono Medium Italic for Powerline.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/Roboto Mono Medium for Powerline.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/Roboto Mono Thin Italic for Powerline.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/Roboto Mono Thin for Powerline.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/Roboto Mono for Powerline.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/RobotoMono-Bold.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/RobotoMono-BoldItalic.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/RobotoMono-Italic.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/RobotoMono-Light.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/RobotoMono-LightItalic.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/RobotoMono-Medium.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/RobotoMono-MediumItalic.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/RobotoMono-Regular.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/RobotoMono-Thin.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/RobotoMono-ThinItalic.ttf
WARNING! stowing fonts would cause conflicts:
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/Roboto Mono Bold Italic for Powerline.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/Roboto Mono Bold for Powerline.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/Roboto Mono Italic for Powerline.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/Roboto Mono Light Italic for Powerline.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/Roboto Mono Light for Powerline.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/Roboto Mono Medium Italic for Powerline.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/Roboto Mono Medium for Powerline.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/Roboto Mono Thin Italic for Powerline.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/Roboto Mono Thin for Powerline.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/Roboto Mono for Powerline.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/RobotoMono-Bold.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/RobotoMono-BoldItalic.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/RobotoMono-Italic.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/RobotoMono-Light.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/RobotoMono-LightItalic.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/RobotoMono-Medium.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/RobotoMono-MediumItalic.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/RobotoMono-Regular.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/RobotoMono-Thin.ttf
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .local/share/fonts/RobotoMono-ThinItalic.ttf
All operations aborted.
fonts stowed.
WARNING! unstowing git would cause conflicts:
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .gitconfig
WARNING! stowing git would cause conflicts:
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .gitconfig
All operations aborted.
git stowed.
gtk stowed.
i3 stowed.
WARNING! unstowing ncmpcpp would cause conflicts:
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .config/ncmpcpp/config
WARNING! stowing ncmpcpp would cause conflicts:
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .config/ncmpcpp/config
All operations aborted.
ncmpcpp stowed.
WARNING! unstowing polybar would cause conflicts:
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .config/polybar/config
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .config/polybar/launch.sh
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .config/polybar/updates.sh
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .config/polybar/weather.py
WARNING! stowing polybar would cause conflicts:
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .config/polybar/config
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .config/polybar/launch.sh
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .config/polybar/updates.sh
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .config/polybar/weather.py
All operations aborted.
polybar stowed.
ranger stowed.
sound stowed.
WARNING! unstowing termite would cause conflicts:
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .config/termite/config
WARNING! stowing termite would cause conflicts:
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .config/termite/config
All operations aborted.
termite stowed.
WARNING! unstowing tmux would cause conflicts:
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .tmux.conf
WARNING! stowing tmux would cause conflicts:
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .tmux.conf
All operations aborted.
tmux stowed.
WARNING! unstowing vim would cause conflicts:
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .tern-config
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .vimrc
WARNING! stowing vim would cause conflicts:
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .tern-config
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .vimrc
All operations aborted.
vim stowed.
WARNING! unstowing xorg would cause conflicts:
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .Xresources
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .xinitrc
WARNING! stowing xorg would cause conflicts:
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .Xresources
  * existing target is neither a link nor a directory: .xinitrc
All operations aborted.
xorg stowed.
All stowed
```

Comment: If my answer helped you solve your problem maybe consider accepting my answer

Answer (score 2):

From which directory are you calling this script? It seems your `cd` is not working, as you are trying to change into `.dotfiles` but the `for` loop is using a directory called `dotfiles` (no leading `.`).

---

#### Meaning of the warnings

It seems that you have *plain* files in your home directory that you would like to be managed (linked) by `stow`.

From the `stow` manual page:

> ```
> --adopt
>     Warning!  This behaviour is specifically intended to alter the contents of your stow directory.  If you do not want that,
>     this option is not for you.
>
>     When stowing, if a target is encountered which already exists but is a plain file (and hence not owned by any existing stow
>     package), then normally Stow will register this as a conflict and refuse to proceed.  This option changes that behaviour so
>     that the file is moved to the same relative place within the package's installation image within the stow directory, and
>     then stowing proceeds as before.  So effectively, the file becomes adopted by the stow package, without its contents
>     changing.
> ```

Direct your attention to this:

> When stowing, if a target is encountered which already exists but is a plain file (and hence not owned by any existing stow package), then normally Stow will register this as a conflict and refuse to proceed.

---

#### TLDR

- Fix your script to point both `cd` and the `for` loop to the same directory: Either `~/.dotfiles/` or `~/dotfiles/`
- If you want to move your existing config files (in `~`) to your `dotfiles` use `stow --adopt` initially (Check the manual beforehand)
- If you want to move your config files from `dotfiles` to your `~` move or delete (backup) the already existing files from your home folder

Answer (score 0):

*I've tried the same approach as you. Here's my attempt at it.*

`cd` does not work on scripts. Instead you'll want to tell `stow` where to stow from instead of the current directory.

I have a bunch of packages in my own dotfiles so I loop through them and stow away:

```sh
for PACKAGE in shell emacs # ...
do
  stow -R -v -d path/to/dotfiles -t ~ $PACKAGE
done
```